# MathML formatting - label is cropped

Tags: mathml

I have some MathJax MathML with a mlabeledtr - a label.

The label is being cropped/cut off as it does not fit inside its parent HTML element so it is not visible.

How do I ensure it is visible?

Comment: You'll need  to provide a sample exhibiting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
config['HTML-CSS'].linebreaks = {automatic: true, width: "90% container"};
```

has done the trick. The label doesn't get accounted for when working out the width, so I had to set the width of the MathML to be smaller (90%) than its container so the label could fit in as well.